# Difference between GIN and Not GIN index on JSONB field

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

Let's say we have an `API` table with the following `jdoc` column (of JSONB type):

```
{
    "guid": "9c36adc1-7fb5-4d5b-83b4-90356a46061a",
    "name": "Angela Barton",
    "is_active": true,
    "company": "Magnafone",
    "address": "178 Howard Place, Gulf, Washington, 702",
    "registered": "2009-11-07T08:53:22 +08:00",
    "latitude": 19.793713,
    "longitude": 86.513373,
    "tags": [
        "enim",
        "aliquip",
        "qui"
    ]
}
```

Most often queries are by `company` field:

```
SELECT jdoc FROM api WHERE jdoc->>'company'='Magnafone'
```

Now what's the most efficent index to have, this one:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON api USING GIN (jdoc);
```

or this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON api (jdoc->>'company')
```

and why?

Comment: The second one because it will be (much) smaller. But the second one will only be useful for that specific json-key, "company". All other queries will be executed using a sequential read.

Answer (score 1):

The GIN index won't work for that query at all, while the 2nd one would.  To get the GIN to work, you would need to write the query like this:

```
WHERE jdoc @> '{"company":"Magnafone"}'
```

That GIN index would also work for fields other than company, but if you don't are about searching other fields than it would just be wasted space.

Comment: Will this query with "@>"  find the same rows as the query in the post?

Comment: @Ekaterina Yes unless I mistyped something.